Monolith project Laravel & React using Vite has very slow and synchronius requests
By for now I develop monolith project. The main problem is that requests take a lot of time and they executes not in async mode.
All requests are in web.php.
vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import laravel from "laravel-vite-plugin";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import path from "path";
import { resolve } from "node:path";
import tsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";

export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        host: "localhost",
    },
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ["resources/ts/main.tsx"],
        }),
        react(),
        tsconfigPaths(),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: [
            {
                find: "@",
                replacement: resolve(__dirname, "./resources/ts"),
                components: `${path.resolve(__dirname, "./resources/ts/Components")}`,
                public: `${path.resolve(__dirname, "./public/")}`,
                pages: path.resolve(__dirname, "./resources/ts/Pages"),
                types: `${path.resolve(__dirname, "./resources/ts/@types")}`,
            },
        ],
    },
});

Example of web.php
// Route to authenticate user
Route::post('/login', [UserAuth::class, 'authenticateUser']);

// Route to return view files (tsx)
Route::get('/{any}', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->where('any', '.*');

I know that provided info won't be enough, but hope you will help me!
Additional info I'll provide as soon as I can!
Problem solves a half when I boot my project on Laravel Octane throw OpenSwoole server. But I think, that it's incorrect and I need to change something in code, but by for now nothing helps.
Also tryied move some request into api.php, but it also didn't helps

Is this in local development? Docker on windows? If so, Laravel has a known problem developing in docker in windows. If not in docker on windows, probably a different issue.

@Mr.Kenneth Yep, it's local development, but not running in docker. I run both console commands like one for Laravel and other - for npm. In one running
php artisan serve
and in other
npm run dev
